# What are the requirements for /mode/html in Ace editor?

Tags: ace-editor

I can get `mode/javascript` working with:

*JS*
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/src-noconflict/ace.js

*Theme*
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/src-noconflict/theme-tomorrow.js

*Mode*
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/src-noconflict/mode-javascript.js

*Worker*
https://raw.github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/master/src-noconflict/worker-javascript.js

*HTML*

```
<script src="/static/js/ace/ace.js"></script>

<div class="my_ace_editor">
function foo(items) {
    var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
    return x;
}
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
#my_ace_editor {
    position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
}
```

*jQuery*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var editor = ace.edit("my_ace_editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/tomorrow");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
});
```

But am not having any luck when attempting to display HTML with:

*HTML*

```
<div id="my_ace_editor"><p>test</p></div>
```

*jQuery*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var editor = ace.edit("my_ace_editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/tomorrow");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
});
```

and have added:

https://raw.github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/master/src-noconflict/mode-html.js

If I type in the HTML editor, the tags and content have syntax highlighting applied.

But it is not showing the actual HTML when it loads - all it shows is `test`.

There are no Firebug errors and I can see the actual HTML that should be highlighted in Firebug.

Is another file or setting required?

**Edit:**  I can get the HTML content within Ace editor showing correctly if I use:

```
editor.setValue("<html>test</html>",-1);
```

But I need to be able to set the value from the HTML itself and not in the jQuery.

The content is being loaded from a database (ie it is 'dynamic content'), i'm not sure if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape html, that is instead of

```
<div id="my_ace_editor"><p>html&test</p></div>
```

it should be

```
<div id="my_ace_editor">&lt;p>html&amp;test&lt;/p></div>
```

This is true for all modes not just html

Comment: I'm using MongoDD.  If I insert this HTML entity (`&lt;`) to the database straight from the shell, Ace editor works correctly.  When using RockMongo (like a phpMyAdmin for MongoDB) it converts the HTML entities to their corresponding characters (ie `&lt;` to `<`) and then Ace editor doesn't produce the desired results.  How do I escape `<` in the RockMongo interface - is that a specific RockMongo issue?

Comment: Or rather, how do I enforce that RockMongo keeps `&lt;` rather than converting it to `<`.

Comment: You shouldn't change it in the datebase, if you are using php use htmlspecialchars function http://am1.php.net/htmlspecialchars#refsect1-function.htmlspecialchars-examples. Also note that this question have nothing to do with ace, and you need to apply same escaping if you wanted to show text in a div.

Comment: The application runs on Python and MongoDB (dynamic query results are dumped in JSON and returned to the `getJSON()` function in jQuery).  I expected when using Ace editor, I would just need to define the div which contained the code (loaded from the database) and it would be rendered within the Ace editor interface correctly.  I've accepted the answer because it answers the original question.  Perhaps I need to look at the encoding of the content from Python to jQuery, or perhaps in jQuery itself. I'll update the original post when I figure out a solution.

Comment: How do you "define the div which contained the code (loaded from the database)" did you think what happens if your code have `<script>alert("hi")</script>`?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to escape the HTML code just use the `script` tag with the following type and style set

```
<script type="text/plain" style="display: block;" id="ace-1">
  <a href="test.html">hello world</a>
  test test
</script>
```